# PDE Linearity Textbook Solution: $\mathscr{L} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + u\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I derived the operator $\mathscr{L} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + u\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}}$ from the PDE $u_x + uu_y = 0$ in order to figure out whether it is linear.

The textbook solutions take the following steps in finding whether the operator is linear:

$$\mathscr{L}(u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + (u + v)\dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}} = \dots = \mathscr{L}u + \mathscr{L}v + uv_y + vu_y,$$

which is obviously nonlinear. But I proceeded as follows:

$$\mathscr{L}(u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + (u)\dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}} = \dots = \mathscr{L}u + \mathscr{L}v,$$

which obviously *is* linear.

I don't understand why the author let $u$ in the operator become $u = u + v$? It seemed to me that, since $u$ is part of the operator, it should remain as $u$ and *not* $u + v$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this. *Why* is it wrong? My point is that $u$ is part of the operator, and the operator is acting upon $(u + v)$, so why is it that $\mathscr{L}(u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + (u + v)\dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}}$ instead of $\mathscr{L}(u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + (u)\dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}}$?

EDIT: For future reference, I would also like to present another interesting example.

Take the operator $\mathscr{L} u = u_x + u_y + 1$. Therefore, $\mathscr{L} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}} + \dfrac{1}{u}$. And so,

$$\mathscr{L} (u + v) = \left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}} + \dfrac{1}{u + v} \right) (u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}} + 1$$

EDIT2:

I think the derivation of $\mathscr{L}$ in the above edit is incorrect. Here is what I think the correct derivation is:

Take the operator $\mathscr{L} u = u_x + u_y + 1$. Therefore, $\mathscr{L} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}} + 1$. And so,

$$\mathscr{L} (u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}} + 1$$

Comment: $\mathscr{L}(u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + (u+v)\dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}}$

Comment: You wrote $u$ in the second term which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @AnubhabGhosal Yes, but *why* is it wrong? My point is that $u$ is part of the operator, and the operator is acting upon $(u + v)$, so why is it that $\mathscr{L}(u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + (u + v)\dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}}$ instead of $\mathscr{L}(u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + (u)\dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}}$?

Comment: $u$ refers to the function itself. In the original equation, you are taking the partial of $u$ wrt $x$ and $y$. To check for linearity you should replace $u$ by $u+v$ everywhere in the expression.

Comment: For example, if $f(x)=x$, then $f(x+y)=x+y$. Similarly, if $\mathscr{L}[u(x,y)] = \dfrac{\partial{(u)}}{\partial{x}} + (u)\dfrac{\partial{(u)}}{\partial{y}}$, $\mathscr{L}[u(x,y) + v(x,y)] = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + (u+v)\dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}}$.

Comment: Your calculation is like showing $f(u) = u^2 $ is linear by first writing $f(u+v) = u(u+v) = \cdots$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes. I haven't done much work with operators, and authors always write it implicitly, rather than explicitly as done in Trebor's answer, so it becomes confusing.

Comment: Somehow the same question was asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413116/some-clarification-on-nonlinear-pdes?rq=1)

Comment: @ArcticChar Ahh, yes, seems like it confused others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me just say that

$$\mathcal L  = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + u\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$

is NOT the correct notation. The above implies that $u$ is a fixed function, and the operator acts as

$$\mathcal L (f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

for all differentiable function $f$.

To avoid confusion, your operator should be written as

$$ \mathcal L' (f) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + f \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

and now it is clear why we have

$$\mathcal L' (f_1+ f_2) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f_1+f_2) + (f_1+f_2) \frac{\partial }{\partial y} (f_1+f_2).$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the notation $$\mathscr{L} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + u\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}}$$ meant $$\mathscr{L}[u] = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + u\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}}.$$ So the $u$ should be replaced too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not too familiar with operators, and the authors never write it explicitly like $\mathscr{L}[u]$, so it becomes confusing.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. In light of this new example, I don't think your notational answer is correct.

Comment: By making that deriviation, you are assuming $\mathscr L$ is linear. You **can't** have $$\mathscr{L} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}} + \dfrac{1}{u}$$ by division.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean we are assuming it is linear? The author of the textbook asks whether the operator $\mathscr{L} u = u_x + u_y + 1$ is linear, so I don't see how there is such an assumption? See the bottom of page 3 for the solution: https://stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/Strauss%20PDEs%202e/Chapter%201/Section%201/Exercise%202/StraussPDEch1s1p02.pdf

Comment: Furthermore, if we follow through with the calculations for $\mathscr{L} (u + v) = \left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}} + \dfrac{1}{u + v} \right) (u + v) = \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial{(u + v)}}{\partial{y}} + 1$, we find that the operator is *not* linear, so I don't see how we are assuming linearity here?

Comment: You know what? The solution $\mathscr{L} (u + v) = \left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}} + \dfrac{1}{u + v} \right) (u + v)$ doesn't make sense to me either. The operator is being treated as if it were being multiplied by (u + v), which doesn't make any sense, since an operator is a mapping.